# htaccess block access to directory but allow access to files

Tags: php, zend-framework, .htaccess, apache2, directory

I have such situation.
I'm developing application in Zend Framework and htaccess pointing every request to
index.php. If some file or directory exists on the request path then htaccess allow access to this files like css, js, images etc...

Now I have for example such link:

**example.com/profile/martin-slicker-i231**

With Zend Router it points to controller account and action viewprofile. I want to add some avatart for my users and I created directory in public folder (so the images would be accessible by the server like css and js). The directory is named "profile" and subdirectory in it is "martin-slicker-i231". All path is visible by server like that:

```
public/
  .htaccess
  index.php
  profile/
    martin-slicker-i231/
      avatar-small.jpg
```

The problem is when i point browser to example.com/profile/martin-slicker-i231 it
points me to this directory not the controller and action. When I remove the  folder with user then the flow go to the controller and action. How to configure .htaccess so the **example.com/profile/martin-slicker-i231** will be pointing to controller and action but request to **example.com/profile/martin-slicker-i231/avatar-small.jpg** point to the file. Here is my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Can somebody help?

Comment: @ Marcin - it looks like the answer below helped you...  Perhaps you should accept it as correct??

Answer (score 4):

Just remove the portion that says that it should serve directories:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l 
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Now it will serve files (with size > 0) and symbolic links directly, but send directory references and other urls to your application

Comment: Yes!!! Thank You very much. It works. I also notice that when I use only this condition: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f it works too. I don't know which way is better but thank You. The portion to serving directories was in oryginal Zend Framework .htaccess file so I hope this won't break anything.

Comment: Since this is the correct answer, you should really accept it by selecting the checkmark next to it.

Comment: Not sure why you didn't get points for this or a acceptance.  It helped me a lot... +1

Answer (score 0):

According to the Apache docs the following will turn off directory listings

```
<Directory /path/to/directory>
   Options -Indexes
</Directory>
```

You might also want to look at the documentation for mod_autoindex

Comment: This gives me 500 Internal Server Error. I changed only path to directory