# Allow Access to files in different server but not directly

Tags: php, image, web-services, security, http

My question is somewhat similar to [htaccess block access to directory but allow access to files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6545155/) but different.

I have a server `X` which serves my file contents 
`www.x.com/allfiles/file1.jpg`.

I have another Server `B` which a user can access through `www.b.com/view.php`

Now i want to serve the `file1.jpg` via `www.b.com`

But if a user visits `www.x.com/allfiles/file1.jpg` he will get a 403 error

But since i have my files in different server i cannot serve them through the `view.php` locally.

What is the workaround ?

What i'm trying to say is I want to keep my `files` in multiple servers and also securely(*so it cant be acessed directly via url*) but only **ONE** SERVER to show them.

Comment: do you want to embed image in view.php via `<img src="http://www.x.com/allfiles/file1.jpg" />`?

Comment: No for example goto https://twitter.com/realdonaldtrump and the first image is hosted on https://pbs.twimg.com/media/C0hd8XhUcAAtpHU.jpg both are different servers. I want the same thing but a security so not anybody can access `https://pbs.twimg.com/media/C0hd8XhUcAAtpHU.jpg ` directly and only from `twitter.com`